# React Contact Form 404 not Found

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to create a contact form in react with node mailer but Im having the following issue:

[Error shown in console on the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkXES.png)

It says that 404 NOT FOUND but I dont know where is the mistake i have tried changing the listening part of the server file but no luck:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import './contactForm.css';
import { Footer } from '../../containers';

const FORM_ENDPOINT = "";


const ContactForm = () => {
    const [status, setStatus] = useState("Submit");
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setStatus("Sending...");
        const { name, email, message } = e.target.elements;
        let details = {
            name: name.value,
            email: email.value,
            message: message.value,
        };
        let response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/contactForm", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(details),
        });
        setStatus("Submit");
        // let result = await response.json();
        // alert(result.status);
    };

  return (
    <div className='RO__ContactForm' id='contactForm'>
        <div className='RO__ContactForm-title'>
            <h3>Contact</h3>
            <h1>I'm here to help you level up</h1>
        </div>
        <div className='RO__ContactForm-content'>
            <div className='RO__ContactForm-content_description'>
                <p>I'm just on click away to help you take your company 
                    to the next level. Fill in the form to share more 
                    details about the project or your favorite movie. 
                    Either way, I'd love to talk.</p>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <form
                className='RO__ContactForm-content_form'
                action = {FORM_ENDPOINT}
                onSubmit = {handleSubmit}
                method = 'POST'
                target='_blank'
                >
                <div className='RO__ContactForm-content_form_name'>
                    <div className='RO__ContactForm-content_form_nameTitle'>
                        <h5>What's your name?</h5>
                    </div>
                    <input 
                        className='RO_ContactForm-content_form_nameInput'
                        type= 'text'
                        id='name'
                        name='name' required 
                    />
                </div>
                <div className='RO__ContactForm-content_form_email'>
                    <div className='RO__ContactForm-content_form_emailTitle'>
                        <h5>Your email</h5>
                    </div>
                    <input
                        className='RO__ContactForm-content_form_emailInput'
                        type='email'
                        id='email['
                        name='email' required
                    />
                </div>
                <div className='RO__ContactForm-content_form_info'>
                    <div className='RO__ContactForm-content_form_infoTitle'>
                        <h5>What can I help you with?</h5>
                    </div>
                    <textarea
                        className='RO__ContactForm-content_form_infoContent'
                        id='message'
                        name='message' required
                    />
                </div>
                <div className='RO__ContactForm-content_form_button'>
                    <button type='submit'>{status}</button>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
        <div className='RO__ContactForm-footer'>
            <Footer  />
        </div>
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default ContactForm
```

and here is the server file that I use to initialize the server to send the email. That file is made for the contact form front end, and the following file (server.js) its the following;:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const cors = require("cors");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/', router);
app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server Running"));

const contactEmail = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "Hotmail",
    auth: {
        user: '*************@hotmail.com',
        pass: '************',
    },
});

contactEmail.verify((error) => {
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
    else{
        console.log("Ready to Send");
    }
});

router.post("/contactForm", (req, res) => {
    const name = rew.body.name;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const message = req.body.message;
    const mail = {
        from: name,
        to: 'invariant.rafael.3096@getDefaultNormalizer.com',
        subject: 'Contact Form Submission',
        hmtl: '<p>Name: ${name} </p> <p>Email: ${email}</p> <p>Message: ${message}</p>',
    };
    contactEmail.sendMail(mail, (error) => {
        if(error){
            res.json({ status: 'Error'});
        }
        else{
            res.json({ status: 'Message Sent' });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

React typically hosts on port 3000. Change the express server to run on a different port: `app.listen(CHANGEME, () => console.log("Server Running"));`

If that doesn't work try making some fetch requests somewhere else e.g. `https://api.publicapis.org/entries` which is a free testing API. Then you will know whether the problem is with your server or not.